# Memorystream object being passed to method doesn't contain values

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream, streamwriter

I am using a memorystream object to write values from streamwriter object into memory. I have several methods which are for logging errors and values so I pass my memorystream object between them as a parameter.

My problem is the memorystream doesn't contain values. See code below:

```
    #region csvlogging
    public static void initiateCsvLogging(SortedList<int, string> logList, SortedList<int, string> errorList) // Handles csv upload logging
    {
        logMsgError(errorList, logList);
    }

    public static void logMsgError(SortedList<int, string> errorList, SortedList<int, string> logList)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
           StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
            try
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Errors:");
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> k in errorList)
                {

                    if (k.Value == null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("No errors reported.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(k.Key + "," + k.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                sw.WriteLine("");
            }

            logMsg(logList, ms);

        }
    } // Handles data upload error logging for csv

    public static MemoryStream logMsg(SortedList<int, string> logList, MemoryStream ms)
    {
        string DateNow = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string FileName = "log " + DateNow + ".csv";
        char[] delimiterChars = { ',' };

        try
        {
            // Write values to textfile and save to Log folder
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                if (logList.Keys.Count == 0)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("No new users added to Active Directory.");
                }
                else  // If keys > 0 then new users have been added to AD
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Username" + "," + "Password" + "," + "Company" + "," + "Email");
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> k in logList)
                    {
                        string[] values = k.Value.Split(delimiterChars);
                        sw.WriteLine(values[0] + "," + values[1] + "," + values[2] + "," + values[3]);
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    sw.Flush();
                    sendLogByEmail(new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()), FileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {

        }

        finally
        {

        }
        return ms;
    } // Handles logging for csv

    public static void sendLogByEmail(MemoryStream ms, string error, int count)
    {
        //Send mail by attachment code
        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
        //smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
        //smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpclient.Host = "ldnmail";


        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("nick.gowdy@orcinternational.co.uk", "nick.gowdy@orcinternational.co.uk");
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
        attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = error;

        message.Attachments.Add(attach);
        smtpclient.Send(message);

    }
    #endregion
```

Because I am not using the USING keyword do I have to write some more code for the memorystream object?

Comment: Can you make it clear at which point the `MemoryStream` is empty against your expectation? Also: empty `catch` immediately make me suspicious... can you comment those out, to see if there is an exception happening?

Comment: I occasionally run into "empty" `MemoryStream`s if I write to them and then try to read without first resetting its `Position` to 0. I can't see if that's your issue, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @MarcGravell I put an ex.tostring() in the empty catch block and there was no exception in the code. Not including flush was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flush (Close) the StreamWriter.

```
        finally
        {
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }

        sw.Flush();             

        logMsg(logList, ms);
```

But in the end you use all data to send it by mail:

```
   System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new
         System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
   System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
```

It would seem a lot easier to collect the information in a StringBuilder through an attached StringWriter.

There are issues with a StreamWriter closing its Stream, that may be part of your problem.

Comment: @HankHolterman Thanks this worked. I read the description for the flush method and it says causes buffered data to be written to the stream. So I guess the data wasnt been written to the memory stream before?